# Creating a URL to direct from one package to another

Tags: redirect, geturl

I have a page in a custom module that gives an admin user the option to view an order's details. When the user clicks the option, I capture their decision in a controller:

```
public function viewAction()
{
    $this->redirect($this->getUrl('*/second_controller/action'), array('id'=>$id) );
}
```

The problem is that I get a URL resembling this:

```
http://webserver/index.php/module_one/second_controller/action/...
```

but what I *need* to get is

```
http://webserver/index.php/module_two/second_controller/action/...
```

I have tried using

```
$this->redirect($this->getUrl('module_two/second_controller/action'), array('id'=>$id) );
```

but with no luck. Does anyone have any idea how this could be done?

Comment: This these admin modules and controllers?

Comment: I changed the names. I've recently started working at a new office, and do not want to put anything online that I don't have to, as I don't know how they feel about it.